# Ajax Post php class not loading problems?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi my problem ajax post after php extends class not loading.
commfuct not found.
There is no problem sending normal (Not using ajax) form.

page.php
User UI

```
include_once("comment.class.php");
$new =new yorum();
$new->commentform($id,$cat);//for example
```

comment.php
Ajax post page

```
inlcude_once("comment.class.php"); 
$new= new comment(); 
if(iseet($_POST)) 
{ 
$cek= $new->yorumkontrol("sa","as@a.com",7,"12sdeaege","bu bir yorum"); 
if(isset($cek["hata"])) 
{ 
echo $cek["hata"]; 
} 
} 
?>
```

Class.php
Php Class file load function

```
class dahilet
{
function autoload($gelen) 
    { 
        $dy=__DIR__."/".$gelen.".sinif.php"; 
        if(file_exists($dy)) 
        { 
            include_once($dy); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
             
            die("$gelen not found."); 
        } 
    }
}
$dosyaknt=new dahilet();
spl_autoload_register(array($dosyaknt,'autoload'));
```

comment.class.php
comment class index
Comment form function 
Comment form control function 
Comment add database function 
commfuct class index
Comment  category control function 
Comment  bot control function 
Comment  gravatar control function 
Comment  google recaptcha control function

```
include_once("class.php");
$dh= new dahilet(); 
$dh->autoload("db"); 
class comment extends  commfunct 
    { 
    function yorumkontrol($a,$b,$c,$d,$e) 
    { 
    $na= self::konumsor($a,$b);
return $na;//for example
    } 
    
    } 
    class commfunct extends baglan 
    { 
      function konumsor($a,$b) 
      { 
      $sql="select * from linksistem where id=:idal,cid=:cidal order by sira asc limit 1"; 
       $sor=$db->prepare($sql); 
       $sor->execute(array("idal"=>$a,"cidal"=>$b)) 
       if(isset($sor->errorInfo()[2])) 
        { 
         if($sor->rowCount()>0) 
         { return false;} 
        else {return true;} 
        } 
       else{return false;} 
      } 
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Put your commfunt class code before comment class code and check

Comment: Did you checked

Comment: @Anant Checked good job problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extend the class commfunct. Here

`class comment extends  commfunct`

But this  `commfunct` class code is below this line and that's  why `commfunct  class not found` error is coming

Solution:-

Put your `commfunct` class  code before extends line and you will good to go

Comment: Glad to help you:):)